# Conditional probability with poisson (can this be solved by binomial?)

Tags: probability, self-study, binomial-distribution, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

Pizza orders arrive according to a Poisson process of rate $20$ per hour. Orders are independently for a vegetarian pizza with probability $\frac14$ , and for a meat pizza with probability $\frac34$.

a. Six orders arrived between 6:45pm and 7:00pm. Given this, what is the probability that fourteen orders arrive between 7:00pm and 7:45pm?

What I tried: I tried this through binomial: $\binom{20}{14} (0.75)^{14} (0.25)^6$.

Is this correct?

b. During a particular 60 minute period, 4 vegetarian orders were received. What is the probability that all 4 of them came during the first 30 minutes?

Why is the answer (30/60)^4 = 1/16

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guide:

- The question is not asking about vegetarian or meat pizza, there is no reason to use all the numbers that is given to you.
- Note that the number of orders between 6:45pm and 7:00pm is independent from the number of orders between 7:00pm and 7:45pm.
- The number of orders between 7:00pm and 7:45pm follows a Poisson distribution, try to find the rate of the Poisson distribution.
- Note that for  Binomial distribution, the setting is there are $n$ events and you want to know how many of them are successful.

Comment: By poisson and combinations method: I took the probability of (6 orders in 15 minutes)* (14 orders in 45 minutes). The entire thing divided by getting 20 order in a hour.

Comment: The mistake I believe I have made is taking into consideration all the other stuff. It should simply be 14 orders in 45 minutes, isn't it?

Comment: $6$ orders in $15$ minutes is irrelevant. It is possible to have more than $21$ orders in $45$ minutes too. also, note that the question is asking about probability.

Comment: If say, it was chronologically in a different order, it would be relevant right? Like, suppose, Probability that 14 orders arrive between 6:45 - 7:30 given that there were 6 orders between 7:30 - 7:45?

Comment: For poisson process, events happening disjoint time intervals are independent, it is still irrelevant.

Comment: If X $\sim$ Pois(15) then $P(X = 14)$ is found in R using `dpois(14, 15)`, which returns 0.1024359. $P(X \ge 14) = 1 - P(X \le 13) \approx .64.$  `1-ppois(13, 15)` returns 0.6367822. in R, `dpois` is a PDF; `ppois` is a CDF.

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh I hope you look at this. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/366118/binomial-poisson-problem-pizza-orders